# html renders different in same browser

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple blog template. In the right corner of the template there is a search box in the header. The search box should appear there, but at some moments it appears under the header.

[image]

This happens every now and then, if I refresh the page a few times the box will somethimes jump positions. I have used `Google Chrome` for the developent The html of this page is purely static, so I don't have a clue why this is happening. Could anyone find out why this box is jumping up and down.

The affected page can be found [here](http://dev.deviaene.eu/tmp/).

Comment: Have you tried resetting the CSS?

Comment: post your code up so that people can see and help more efficiently

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 32

Comment: Its working fine in IE 10

Comment: Can reproduce in chrome. If I then resize the screen It pops to the correct place. I would suspect the mediaquery causing this.

Comment: Personally I would use absolute positioning for this. Make the header wrapper position:relative, then searchBox position:absolute, right:10px, top:10px, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't re-create your problem, but I'm sure adding `position:relative` to either `nav` or `.wrapper`

```
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

and `position:absolute` to the searchbox will prevent any jumping.

```
header#top #searchBox {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 45px;
  // line-height, any other styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
header#top #searchBox{
float: right;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 45px;
width: 63%;

text-align: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple,

just ad float: left; to the menu element ( header#top nav ul)

```
header#top nav ul {
list-style: none;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

than you will only need to add height to the wrapper

```
.wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 46px;
}
```